# Emunah and failures?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, free-will-bechira, hashgacha-pratit, breslov

Rav Arush in the *Garden of Emunah* apparently has a concept that failures are from Hashem [see here](https://m.breslev.co.il/articles/spirituality_and_faith/spiritual_growth/the_levels_of_emuna.aspx?id=1454&language=english) :

> Before making a mistake, a person has apparent free choice not to make a mistake. But, after the fact, one must believe that Hashem willed the mistake!

Are there any other sources that discuss such a thing? What do they say?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Yosef_Leiner

Comment: Basically the question of free will vs destiny?

Comment: @Ilja: I don't think so, although Yoda would disagree with me. Free Will is about try or not try. Destiny doesn't require mistakes; it could be implemented entirely with failed attemps (do or not do).

Comment: @JoelK: Yes, I am sure this is Izhbitz. If not the rebbe, then maybe R Tzadoq of Lublin. (Or is R Tzadoq only studied by Litvaks with an interest in chassidus? <grin>)  You should flesh out a full answer.